# Getting a boolean array out of connection status

Tags: .net, powershell, networking

I want to make a powershell scrip which will return some information(Hostname, OS, SP) about each computer that is connected to the network.

At the moment I try to pick the IP addresses which are used and store them in an array for later use.

My problem is that I try to get the status of the connection (successful/timed out/host unreachable) and if it is successful to add it to the array via an if statement.

```
$computerAddress = (1..254)

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$workingComputers = @()

$ping = New-Object System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping

[string]$result=""

foreach($computer in $computerAdress){
    $result = $ping.Send("10.0.0.$computer") | select status
    $result -eq "Status=Success"
}
```

The problem is with $result -eq "Status=Success", it always returns false, even if it is a Successful ping.

Please lend a hand to an intern. Also I beg of you no answers without an explanation because I do not want to copy but to learn.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as FoxDeploy said is a problem with how I took the Status field out of the Ping object.

The way I found is :

```
$ping.Send("10.0.0.$computer") | select status | %{$_.Status -eq "Success"}
```

Basically I pass the object via the second pipe ("|") and then I select just the Status field (very similar to Java) :))

Thanks again FoxDeploy for giving me and insight!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem!

You're storing the results of a `$ping.Send()` within `$result`, selecting only the `.Status` property.

That means your `$result` object looks like this:

```
>$result

Status
------
Success
```

You're then asking PowerShell to compare this to "Status=Success".  The character's don't exactly match, which is what `-eq` / equals is built to find out.

Now, if you want to **directly** compare the Status property to see if it was a Success or not, you do that by typing `$Result.Status`, to pluck out just that one property and throw away the column header.  You can then throw out the "Status=" part of the comparison, it's not needed.

This is what the comparison should look like then.

```
$result.Status -eq "Success"
True
```

If you'd like any further clarification, please let me know :)

Comment: Your explication is very good  (it make a lot of sense):D I will test it tomorrow and if it works I will select is as answer. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hello,

I tried what you said and did not work. I will place it as a link cuz it is a meas otherwise.

Here is what is shows [link](http://1drv.ms/1NKzuSg)

I think what you said about $result having a field named Status is not applying in my case because if I let it be $result.Status is not showing anything, but if I let it be $result is what you see in the first half.|

In the second half you see the result of $result -eq "Status==Success".

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I succeeded by doing it in one line :D 

$ping.Send("10.0.0.$computer") | select status | %{$_.Status -eq "Success"}